# Server only accessible via Memshell

Tags: windows-server-2008

We appear to of been hacked, we have a new  users (now removed) and some adware (quarantined) but it's taken out Malware bytes and there's no access externally to any of our websites and I can not FTP in either.

Where might I look next?! I want to back up the SQL and get it down to a backup PC and then restore the server. But I've no idea how to get the FTP working again.

We had Filezilla on and I'll take it off and put it back on but no joy.

Apologies for lack of grace in the question, stress day!

Comment: I'm running updates, just encase but someone just suggested I check the settings on Windows Advanced Firewalling

Comment: You need to hire a consultant to restore the servers. "no idea how to do this" indicates that you cannot do this by yourself.

Comment: I meant no idea how to get back in with FTP atm, I've amended they query so hopefully read correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out that in the Firewall settings everything had been turned off. I had a export of the windows firewall policy so I pasted this back and working now.

Worth taking a export of your windows firewall once you are set up and make changes.